# While creating an R package the error has arisen

Tags: r, package

Last week I was training to create a user-defined package in R. 
As the tutorial I used this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PyQlbAEujY. 
I used R-studio Version 0.99.486.

Everything worked well, I made a package: ran build&reload -> check and build -> build a binary package
While creating a package, I was using devtools and roxygen2 libraries.

But today I have the error (after pressing  “check”) that I can’t find a clue how to fix it. To create a package on the work station is ok, but for my network directory \dc2\mypackage.

The trouble seems to be with the acces to c:\windows. However I have got some security issues to get rid of all restrictions. 
So it seems to be another way ((if it is ever) to redefine check (log) directory.

I would be grateful for your help with the error at \dc2\mypackage:

The snapshot of check window:

```
==> devtools::check(document = FALSE)

Setting env vars ---------------------------------------------------------    
CFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
CXXFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
Building mypackage ----------------------------------------------------------
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
--no-restore CMD build  \
"\\dc2\mypackage"  \
--no-resave-data --no-manual 

* checking for file '\\dc2\mypackage/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'mypackage':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'mypackage_0.1.tar.gz'

pdflatex not found! Not building PDF manual or vignettes.
If you are planning to release this package, please run a check with manual and vignettes beforehand.

Setting env vars -----------------------------------------------------------
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_ : FALSE
_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: FALSE
Checking mypackage ----------------------------------------------------------
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
--no-restore CMD check  \
"C:\Users\DEMYD~1.DZY\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8eHzkB/mypackage_0.1.tar.gz"  \
--as-cran --timings --no-build-vignettes --no-manual 

"\\dc2\Risk_Management\Score_card_DEV\R\packages"
��������� ���� ��� �ᯮ�짮��� ��� ����᪥ CMD.EXE �        �����⢥ ⥪�饩 �����.
CMD.EXE �� �����ন���� ���� UNC. �� 㬮�砭�� ���࠭�   ���⥬��� ����� Windows.
ERROR: cannot create check dir 'C:/Windows/mypackage.Rcheck'
Error in lapply(list(...), quotes) : object 'Log' not found
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Have you checked the folder it can't create? If it's there try removing it; if not, I don't know much about windows, but maybe you don't have permission to write to the c:/windows folder?

Comment: Here is what I use to create my packages (quickest guide I found): http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/

Comment: @  Lev Kuznetsov:
I will try but it is strange that a package at work station does not require to be written to C (it is written to D disk) disk but for network placement.

Comment: @  NBATrends: thanks for demo. It seems to be interesting. I use http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html but it is too detiled without overall example.

Comment: I would start debugging with going to building and checking from the console using `R CMD build` and `R CMD check`, use `--help` argument to read about them.

Comment: @ jangorecki: thanks, i will try your proposal